# Angular2 || How to gave two inputs to child component.?

Tags: angular

I have two components.

Parent-component and child component, I need to pass two type of data to child-component.
One data is JSON
second data is String.

**CHILD COMPONENT**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'child',
      template: `<h1>{{header}}</h1>
<p>{{data}}</p>`,
    })
    export class child implements OnInit {
     //DECLERATIONS
      @Input('location-Data') data:string;
      header:string;
      data:string;
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

**Parent component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-standard-order',
  template: ' <location-selector [location-Data]='Sample Data}'></location-selector>',
})
export class StandardOrderComponent implements OnInit {


  //DECLERATIONS

  header: string
  reqDeliveryDate: string = "";


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTodaysDate();
  }



}
```

Here you can see that I have given an input from host component to child component namely location-data. it's working, I can print sample data!!
The next thing I need to input another string from host to the child component namely header. 
Can anybody suggest me a method to solve this?

Comment: U are not accepting your header as input, who need to accept the value same as location-data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still pass data from parent to child with input binding for other properties as:

```
@Input('location-Data') data:string;
@Input header:string;
```

You can find out more at [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child)

Hope this help!

Comment: I had tried this, but the confussion is how to include this new in put at host template ? 
 <location-selector [header]="header1" [location-Data]='Sample Data}'></location-selector>',
Like that ?

Comment: you can use: <location-selector [location-Data]='Sample Data}' [header]="header"></location-selector>